# Re-email the lost issues of 'The Overflow'

Tags: support, email, subscriptions, the-overflow

I look forward to my weekly dose of 'The Overflow' which I get via email because I subscribed a while back. However, for the last two weeks I did not get the newsletter email. It seems my email settings reset or something (I don't remember changing anything). Although I have fixed them now.

So my question is this: is it possible to get the emails for those issues that I have lost? (issues #45 and #46 to be precise)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt there is any way to have old, missed issues re-sent as emails, but I'm not sure why it would be necessary. All issues of "The Overflow" are available online, on the Stack Overflow Blog:

https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/

They are tagged as "newsletter", so you can find them all in one place. The emails are just a copy of what is hosted online.

Here are issues #45 and #46:

- [The Overflow #45: What we call CI/CD is actually only CI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/10/30/the-overflow-45-what-we-call-ci-cd-is-actually-only-ci/)
- [The Overflow #46: What does it mean to be a product-led company](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/11/06/the-overflow-46-what-does-it-mean-to-be-a-product-led-company/)

There is also [an RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/feed/), in case that delivery system might be more convenient.